# What values I can use for the $code property of a custom PHP exception

Tags: php

The PHP exception documentation found on the [official PHP website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) states that the default value for the `$code` property of the `Exception` class, if not provided explicitly, is `0`:

```
public __construct(string $message = "", int $code = 0, ?Throwable $previous = null)
```

So whenever I implement a custom Exception, I can specify a custom exception code by passing it to the `parent::__construct()` call.

However, I haven't found any information regarding what codes, if any, are reserved for the standard PHP exceptions, like the `RuntimeException`. Do they all set this property to `0` and I can put whatever value I want in my custom exceptions?

Comment: You can also read the user comments in the PHP manual for the `Exception::getCode()` method to understand what they are for and how you can use it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php - Personally, I've never needed to use any custom code when throwing exceptions. I prefer to write a short message instead.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed those comments.